# Why the number of rows affected is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is my query:

```
SELECT u.password, r.active 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN resend_pass r
ON u.id = r.user_id
WHERE r.token = 'mytoken' AND r.active = 1
```

The result of query above is this:

```
+----------+--------+
| password | active |
+----------+--------+
| mypass   | 1      |
+----------+--------+
```

**Note:** `token` column is unique, so the result always is **one** row *(or zero row)*.

---

Now I convert that `select` statement to a `update` statement like this:

```
UPDATE users u
INNER JOIN resend_pass r
ON u.id = r.user_id
SET u.password = 'mynewpass',
    r.active   = 0
WHERE r.token  = 'mytoken' AND
      r.active = 1
```

And then the result will be like this:

```
+-----------+--------+
| password  | active |
+-----------+--------+
| mynewpass | 0      |
+-----------+--------+
```

---

Ok well, all fine. just I don't know why  the number of rows affected is `2`? As you see there is just one row and I've updated two columns of one row, so why row affected is `2`?

```
echo $stm->rowCount(); // 2
```

Shouldn't it be `1` ?

Comment: you are updating 2 rows one each in tables `users` and `resend_pass`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SET u.password = 'mynewpass',
    r.active   = 0
```

thats 2 rows one in each table *aliased* by u and r.

Comment: Ah I see thx .. +1 .. *(however 5 upvotes is much for this answer, enjoy it)*

Comment: @stack I post here not to earn points ... if there was a way i would transfer all my points and badges to you. cheers.

Comment: Wow .. that's nice of you. `:-)`